# zlib, c and gzread

Tags: c, zlib

so I'm using the zlib package on Ubuntu. I'm trying to figure out how to use gzopen and gzread correctly, this is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <zlib.h>

#define NUM_BUFFERS 8
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 1024

char buf[BUFFER_LENGTH];
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int status;
    gzFile file;
    file = gzopen("beowulf.txt", "w");
    int counter = 0; /*when the counter reachers BUFFERS_FULL, stop*/
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("COULD NOT OPEN FILE\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(counter < NUM_BUFFERS)
    {
        status = gzread(file, buf, BUFFER_LENGTH - 2);
        printf("STATUS: %d\n", status);
        buf[BUFFER_LENGTH - 1] = "\0";
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        counter++;
    }
    gzclose(file);
    printf("STATUS: %d\n", status);
    return 0;
}
```

The `gzread("STATUS: %d\n",status);` returns -2, and I have no clue why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mode `"w"` indicates that you are preparing to **create** a new archive:

```
file = gzopen("beowulf.txt", "w");
```

You've just truncated the file to zero length.

Also, you should use the binary mode flag: `"wb"` or `"rb"`.

Also, it's a bit weird that your supposed .gz-archive has an extension `.txt`.

Read the [docs](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip), docs rule. :)

Comment: oh. In fact, the docs for gzread indicate that it can read anything, I was just trying to determine that it wasn't the decompression that was screwing with the functionality of my program.

Comment: @Sam It probably didn't like to read from a write-mode stream, hence Z_STREAM_ERROR. Of course you don't need the `b` mode for reading a text file; I thought you were trying to read an archive.

Comment: so I should use the b mode if I am reading an archive? That's the next step in this here :)

Comment: @Sam `b` mode is for binary files (as opposed to text files). It's the same `b` flag as in `fopen`. On Unix-ish systems it has no effect, but it's a good habit to use it anyway. On other OSes it controls end-of-line conversion and possibly other things. E.g. on Windows, byte with value 26 (ASCII EOF) causes end-of-file for text files.

Answer (score 1):

Log the error type using function `gzerror()`. Since it is -2, it won't be an end-of-file error. Possibly any of the following errors.

```
Z_DATA_ERROR
```

A CRC error occurred when reading data; the file is corrupt.

```
Z_STREAM_ERROR
```

The stream is invalid, or is in an invalid state.

```
Z_NEED_DICT
```

A dictionary is needed (see inflateSetDictionary()).

```
Z_MEM_ERROR
```

Insufficient memory available to decompress.

Comment: -2 is Z_STREAM_ERROR. But I have no idea what that means or how to fix it

Comment: You haven't called `gzerror` yet, so you don't know what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

From http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/zlib-gzread-1.html :

1. If the return is positive it is the number of bytes read, you can use that to put the NULL terminator in the right place.
2. You can use `gzerror` if the return code is `<0` to work out what the error is.